# Encoding in pdf with libharu library

Tags: c, character-encoding, libharu

I'm trying to create a pdf document with help of [libharu library](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki) version 2.3.
Everything goes fine except for encoding. I need to insert Central European language (Czech). Source code saved as utf-8 and compiled under Linux gcc.
In function HPDF_GetFont() I've tried all of [single byte encodings](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Encodings) and all of buildin fonts and fonts from file with utf-8 support. But that's not the way to success.
 What should I change in the code below?
Should I save text "abcdÁéěňóšťíď" to wchar_t* and then convert it to singlebyte somehow?
Thanks for advice.

```
void write_to_pdf(char *file_name)
{
    HPDF_Doc pdf;
    HPDF_Page page;
    HPDF_Font font;

    pdf = HPDF_New (NULL, NULL);
    if (!pdf) 
    {
        printf ("ERROR: cannot create pdf object.\n");
        return false;
    }

    HPDF_UseUTFEncodings(pdf);

    font = HPDF_GetFont(pdf, HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile(pdf, "arial.ttf", HPDF_TRUE), "StandardEncoding");
    page = HPDF_AddPage(pdf);
    HPDF_Page_SetSize (page, HPDF_PAGE_SIZE_A4, HPDF_PAGE_PORTRAIT);
    HPDF_Page_SetTextRenderingMode(page, HPDF_FILL);
    HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill(page, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize(page, font, 11);
    HPDF_Page_BeginText(page);
    HPDF_Page_TextOut(page, 10, 20, "abcdÁéěňóšťíď");
    HPDF_Page_EndText(page);

    HPDF_SaveToFile (pdf, file_name);
    HPDF_Free (pdf);
}
```

In pdf file characters "Áéěňóšťíď" are not printed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved problem by adding:
     `HPDF_SetCurrentEncoder(pdf, "UTF-8")`
and UTF-8 to fnc:
      `HPDF_GetFont(pdf, HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile(pdf, "arial.ttf", HPDF_TRUE), "UTF-8")`
I did not find this in documentation but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125242/german-text-not-proper-on-pdf-created-by-libharu-c). Maybe doc is not uptodate.