# const char* cppString to NSString not working if it contains smiles

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have cpp `const char* string` which contains `" playlist"` characters.
I am trying to convert it into `NSString` and I am getting `"@(NULL)"` string.

Following are my steps to convert it.

```
 string cppString = " playlist"; //Cpp data type
```

1. I have one method where I am passing my cpp string like

`NSString *str = [self charStringToString:cppString.c_str()];`

and the method returns `NSString` object after some operations:

```
+ (NSString *)charStringToString:(const char*)cppStringConst
{
   if ( cppStringConst == NULL || cppStringConst == nullptr  )
   {
      return @"";
   }
   NSString *outputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cppStringConst]];
   if ( [outputString isEqualToString:@"(null)"] == YES )
   {
      //it should not come here if I am passing  playlist
        return @"";
   }
   return outputString;
}
```

Could anyone resolve my problem??

Comment: This does not look like C code at all...possibly tagged incorrectly?

Comment: Yes @ChrisTunner, I am trying to convert Cpp code(String) into Objective-C.

Comment: Are you sure that your `cppString` contains a valid UTF8 encoding?

Comment: What encoding is your file set to in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23283133/422156) to a similar question. I'm suspicious of the encoding being used in your `const char *` string.